# Who can write a more efficient query?

Tags: sql-server

I have this query, which works, but is there a more efficient way to write it?

```
SELECT *
FROM table (NOLOCK)  
WHERE ((COL1 = 'aaa' AND COL2 = 'ee')
       OR (COL1 = 'bbb' AND COL2 = 'ff')
       OR (COL1 = 'ccc' AND COL2 = 'gg'))
```

Comment: Why are you using `NOLOCK`, out of interest? Are you happy with your query possibly returning incorrect results? And the only thing that going to help effeciency here are covering indexes.

Comment: No discussion needed - just stop splattering [nolock everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

First you will need a composite index with both COL1 and COL2 on the same index.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TABLE_COL1_COL2
ON table (COL1, COL2);
```

Then I would use a union of simpler queries, that the engine won't have problems optimizing individually through the previous index. Expressions with OR seems to be harder for the engine to locate an optimal execution plan.

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE COL1 = 'aaa' AND COL2 = 'ee'

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE COL1 = 'bbb' AND COL2 = 'ff'

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE COL1 = 'ccc' AND COL2 = 'gg'
```